# Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension (ope-rb gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to install this **ope-rb** gem in my project. Here, the **native.c** is the gem source program it seems.  Since it couldn't find the **openssl/rand.h** header file, it throws an error. Can anyone tell me what am I missing?

```
Fetching ope-rb 0.0.1
Installing ope-rb 0.0.1 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/matheswka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180821-27089-1aspxw9.rb extconf.rb
checking for openssl/ssl.h... no
checking for SSLv23_method() in -lssl... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling native.c
native.c:3:10: fatal error: 'openssl/rand.h' file not found
#include <openssl/rand.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [native.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/matheswka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@appointments/gems/ope-rb-0.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/matheswka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@appointments/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/ope-rb-0.0.1/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing ope-rb (0.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ope-rb -v '0.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Seems like you need to install a package `libssl-dev` first.

Comment: It worked when I run in ruby 2.2.10